# Plot 1st column as X-axis and 2nd and 3rd columns on Y-axis in R with published quality

Tags: r

```
 Distance   Same Strand     Opposite Strand

-200    72921.0 68993.0
-199    73215.0 68720.0
-198    73013.0 69026.0
-197    72769.0 68502.0
-196    72898.0 68953.0
-195    73029.0 68626.0
-194    73004.0 69227.0
-193    73696.0 69107.0
-192    73377.0 69610.0
-191    73320.0 69225.0
-190    73476.0 69259.0
-189    73720.0 69073.0
-188    73633.0 69443.0
-187    73916.0 69000.0
-186    73985.0 69150.0
-185    74523.0 69445.0
-184    74160.0 69556.0
-183    74079.0 69690.0
-182    74363.0 69143.0
-181    74349.0 69507.0
-180    74201.0 69332.0
-179    74171.0 69569.0
-178    74151.0 69139.0
-177    74589.0 69716.0
-176    74506.0 69760.0
-175    74202.0 69724.0
-174    74736.0 69896.0
-173    74335.0 69667.0
-172    74956.0 69839.0
-171    74866.0 69514.0
-170    75318.0 69675.0
-169    75002.0 69835.0
-168    75059.0 70338.0
-167    75400.0 69965.0
-166    75361.0 70031.0
-165    75173.0 70157.0
-164    75773.0 69671.0
-163    75643.0 69889.0
-162    75765.0 70222.0
-161    75883.0 70139.0
-160    76207.0 70205.0
-159    75976.0 70093.0
-158    76202.0 70226.0
-157    76391.0 70341.0
-156    76471.0 70315.0
-155    77016.0 70382.0
-154    76173.0 70383.0
-153    77206.0 70738.0
-152    77187.0 70542.0
-151    77170.0 70609.0
-150    76779.0 70628.0
-149    77463.0 70826.0
-148    77219.0 70261.0
-147    77285.0 70443.0
-146    77232.0 70719.0
-145    76891.0 70972.0
-144    78394.0 70603.0
-143    77843.0 70676.0
-142    77674.0 71312.0
-141    78086.0 71077.0
-140    78585.0 70893.0
-139    78402.0 71089.0
-138    78390.0 70900.0
-137    79078.0 71238.0
-136    78847.0 71475.0
-135    79232.0 70709.0
-134    79278.0 71215.0
-133    79370.0 71043.0
-132    79550.0 71190.0
-131    79434.0 71445.0
-130    79776.0 71015.0
-129    80030.0 71550.0
-128    80179.0 71031.0
-127    80580.0 70868.0
-126    80943.0 71512.0
-125    80588.0 71328.0
-124    81144.0 71425.0
-123    81218.0 71377.0
-122    81059.0 71799.0
-121    81227.0 71715.0
-120    81782.0 71642.0
-119    81854.0 71833.0
-118    81894.0 71607.0
-117    82288.0 71656.0
-116    82570.0 71754.0
-115    82651.0 71806.0
-114    83284.0 71944.0
-113    83549.0 71697.0
-112    83052.0 72335.0
-111    83520.0 72272.0
-110    83944.0 72609.0
-109    83792.0 71774.0
-108    84347.0 72423.0
-107    84482.0 71901.0
-106    84558.0 72259.0
-105    85455.0 72231.0
-104    85336.0 72870.0
-103    86137.0 72672.0
-102    85739.0 72971.0
-101    85761.0 72717.0
-100    85906.0 72631.0
-99 86324.0 72881.0
-98 87210.0 73265.0
-97 87456.0 72509.0
-96 87983.0 73539.0
-95 87872.0 73176.0
-94 88470.0 72934.0
-93 88485.0 73049.0
-92 88540.0 73220.0
-91 89259.0 73873.0
-90 89612.0 73600.0
-89 89882.0 73316.0
-88 90401.0 73672.0
-87 90841.0 73598.0
-86 90466.0 73342.0
-85 91514.0 73899.0
-84 91243.0 73912.0
-83 91564.0 73699.0
-82 92506.0 74030.0
-81 92748.0 73751.0
-80 92896.0 73759.0
-79 93618.0 74410.0
-78 93683.0 74293.0
-77 94098.0 74377.0
-76 94440.0 74360.0
-75 95117.0 74405.0
-74 95563.0 73934.0
-73 95613.0 74548.0
-72 95941.0 74570.0
-71 96721.0 74731.0
-70 96405.0 74969.0
-69 96972.0 74923.0
-68 97588.0 74600.0
-67 98112.0 75341.0
-66 98494.0 75452.0
-65 99285.0 75497.0
-64 98649.0 75178.0
-63 100187.0    74821.0
-62 99935.0 75486.0
-61 100138.0    75688.0
-60 101024.0    75473.0
-59 101001.0    75708.0
-58 101675.0    75690.0
-57 101730.0    76173.0
-56 102024.0    75995.0
-55 103112.0    75819.0
-54 103467.0    75993.0
-53 103442.0    75608.0
-52 103890.0    76486.0
-51 104053.0    76358.0
-50 104710.0    76890.0
-49 105331.0    76343.0
-48 105636.0    76447.0
-47 105414.0    76993.0
-46 105794.0    77160.0
-45 106454.0    76777.0
-44 106738.0    76730.0
-43 107590.0    76803.0
-42 106816.0    77058.0
-41 108022.0    77383.0
-40 108171.0    77245.0
-39 108684.0    77635.0
-38 109207.0    78123.0
-37 109539.0    78041.0
-36 109904.0    78571.0
-35 110033.0    77923.0
-34 111188.0    78353.0
-33 111034.0    78075.0
-32 111585.0    78750.0
-31 112577.0    78296.0
-30 112361.0    78616.0
-29 113187.0    78122.0
-28 113998.0    78677.0
-27 114267.0    79058.0
-26 114556.0    78973.0
-25 114995.0    79087.0
-24 115552.0    79091.0
-23 115534.0    79169.0
-22 116628.0    79601.0
-21 117571.0    79518.0
-20 117620.0    79517.0
-19 119023.0    80213.0
-18 119028.0    80385.0
-17 119864.0    79914.0
-16 120960.0    80636.0
-15 121400.0    80175.0
-14 121820.0    80904.0
-13 122038.0    81333.0
-12 122952.0    80598.0
-11 123894.0    80220.0
-10 124425.0    80675.0
-9  124651.0    81300.0
-8  125893.0    81650.0
-7  126920.0    81695.0
-6  127751.0    81914.0
-5  129451.0    81583.0
-4  130018.0    82346.0
-3  133223.0    82115.0
-2  134779.0    82705.0
-1  137353.0    82569.0
0   0.0 83326.0
1   137163.0    82977.0
2   135196.0    82774.0
3   133497.0    82593.0
4   130651.0    83500.0
5   129303.0    83940.0
6   128146.0    84929.0
7   126836.0    86017.0
8   126109.0    86628.0
9   125409.0    87713.0
10  124839.0    88630.0
11  123980.0    88935.0
12  123790.0    89560.0
13  122945.0    89995.0
14  121828.0    90201.0
15  121354.0    91454.0
16  121096.0    92273.0
17  120102.0    93262.0
18  119685.0    93623.0
19  118981.0    94554.0
20  118500.0    95273.0
21  117441.0    96015.0
22  117068.0    96287.0
23  116692.0    96828.0
24  115958.0    97981.0
25  115521.0    98520.0
26  113491.0    99397.0
27  114670.0    100201.0
28  113684.0    101167.0
29  113060.0    101513.0
30  112752.0    102472.0
31  112669.0    103842.0
32  112035.0    105707.0
33  112024.0    106112.0
34  111086.0    107014.0
35  110152.0    108456.0
36  110719.0    107114.0
37  109920.0    107182.0
38  109881.0    106958.0
39  108927.0    106537.0
40  108664.0    106012.0
41  108226.0    105727.0
42  107561.0    105794.0
43  107454.0    105502.0
44  107267.0    105797.0
45  107211.0    105795.0
46  106682.0    105360.0
47  105803.0    105275.0
48  105920.0    105530.0
49  105776.0    106029.0
50  104846.0    106448.0
51  104282.0    106472.0
52  104327.0    106625.0
53  103735.0    106832.0
54  103176.0    105944.0
55  103062.0    106590.0
56  102556.0    106739.0
57  102233.0    106577.0
58  101465.0    107290.0
59  101129.0    106767.0
60  100262.0    107423.0
61  100521.0    107469.0
62  100038.0    108041.0
63  99903.0 107556.0
64  99095.0 108180.0
65  98826.0 108752.0
66  98276.0 108536.0
67  97732.0 109795.0
68  97872.0 110050.0
69  97770.0 110165.0
70  97335.0 110036.0
71  96700.0 110566.0
72  95985.0 111632.0
73  96023.0 110801.0
74  95083.0 111629.0
75  94857.0 112844.0
76  95273.0 112685.0
77  94685.0 113642.0
78  94270.0 113828.0
79  94052.0 114767.0
80  93268.0 114440.0
81  92720.0 115629.0
82  92631.0 115444.0
83  92064.0 116660.0
84  91506.0 116953.0
85  91824.0 117477.0
86  91291.0 117528.0
87  90597.0 118202.0
88  90421.0 117925.0
89  90057.0 118776.0
90  90194.0 118442.0
91  89277.0 118899.0
92  89398.0 119347.0
93  89299.0 119456.0
94  88972.0 119563.0
95  88114.0 119474.0
96  87983.0 119743.0
97  88109.0 119276.0
98  87320.0 120361.0
99  87347.0 119427.0
100 86743.0 119536.0
101 86534.0 119997.0
102 86322.0 120521.0
103 85897.0 120115.0
104 85724.0 119567.0
105 85741.0 120111.0
106 85285.0 120132.0
107 84324.0 119549.0
108 84603.0 119211.0
109 84034.0 119732.0
110 84066.0 119270.0
111 83712.0 118527.0
112 83973.0 118944.0
113 83510.0 118368.0
114 82797.0 118481.0
115 82858.0 118074.0
116 82725.0 117674.0
117 82528.0 117960.0
118 82110.0 117519.0
119 82033.0 117412.0
120 82319.0 116730.0
121 81862.0 116151.0
122 81386.0 116562.0
123 81239.0 116190.0
124 81211.0 115550.0
125 80959.0 115554.0
126 80940.0 114977.0
127 80656.0 114838.0
128 80268.0 114437.0
129 80079.0 113920.0
130 79995.0 114240.0
131 79257.0 113148.0
132 79945.0 112985.0
133 79876.0 112360.0
134 79080.0 112169.0
135 79196.0 111983.0
136 79231.0 112377.0
137 78765.0 110854.0
138 78683.0 111927.0
139 78765.0 110332.0
140 78298.0 110610.0
141 78474.0 109761.0
142 78328.0 109729.0
143 77743.0 109234.0
144 78381.0 108824.0
145 77866.0 108426.0
146 77769.0 107735.0
147 77664.0 107621.0
148 77235.0 107666.0
149 76941.0 106655.0
150 76996.0 106982.0
151 77378.0 105561.0
152 77587.0 105598.0
153 77340.0 105271.0
154 76761.0 105314.0
155 76612.0 104486.0
156 76252.0 103923.0
157 76438.0 103819.0
158 76238.0 103376.0
159 76432.0 103135.0
160 76050.0 102447.0
161 75923.0 101709.0
162 75729.0 101613.0
163 75958.0 100854.0
164 75922.0 100868.0
165 76059.0 101341.0
166 75591.0 100013.0
167 75824.0 100056.0
168 75698.0 99580.0
169 74998.0 98717.0
170 75501.0 98472.0
171 75511.0 98570.0
172 75227.0 97737.0
173 74910.0 97683.0
174 75346.0 96867.0
175 74712.0 97201.0
176 74731.0 97016.0
177 74738.0 95997.0
178 75046.0 96051.0
179 75309.0 95692.0
180 74759.0 95561.0
181 74321.0 94872.0
182 74104.0 94390.0
183 74713.0 94281.0
184 74136.0 93894.0
185 74175.0 93588.0
186 73985.0 92636.0
187 74091.0 92399.0
188 73881.0 92427.0
189 74028.0 91944.0
190 73855.0 91524.0
191 73694.0 91465.0
192 73912.0 91051.0
193 73314.0 90738.0
194 73428.0 90588.0
195 73010.0 90205.0
196 73578.0 90185.0
197 73076.0 89798.0
198 73072.0 89194.0
199 73144.0 88873.0
200 73022.0 88455.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addition to using lines, you can also use the `matplot` function.

Or you can use lattice graphics with a command something like:

```
xyplot( y1 + y2 ~ x, data=mydata, type='l' )
```

Comment: Yes it is working great. Is it possible to tweak to make it publishable quality figure?

Comment: It is possible to tweak most graphs, what about the current graph is less than publication quality that you would like to change?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for:

```
plot(dfr[,1], dfr[,2], type="l")
lines(dfr[,1], dfr[,3], col="red")
```